# Hash object in SAS - is it possible to concatenate two tables below using hash object?

Tags: sas, concatenation, hashtable

I'm trying to find ways to substitute all possible proc sql and regular merges with hash whenever possible.
Sample data looks like

```
data TABLE1;
input Date Property $6. Headcount;
datalines;
01Jul2013 East  100
02Jul2013 East  50
02Jul2013 West  50
;
run;

data TABLE2;
input Date Property $6. Headcount;
datalines;
11Aug2013 East  60
02Oct2013 East  50
22Dec2013 West  40
run;
```

Both data sets are already sorted by `Date` and `Property`. Currently I do it via

```
data WANT;
set TABLE1 TABLE2;
run;
```

But the problem is the total number of records in both tables are quite large. The codes above require 20mins or even more to finish this concatenation.

I do know how to use hash object to obtain a outer join result. But how to use it for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Do you subsequently use your `WANT` datastep in other steps (data or proc), e.g. to summarize or subset it down?

If so, you can reduce the I/O by specifying `WANT` as a view instead of a table.

```
data want /view=want ;
  set table1 table2 ;
run ;

/* Then use `want` elsewhere... */
proc summary data=want ... ;
  ... 
run ;
```

BUT... if you use `want` several times, it may still be more efficient (in terms or time or I/O) to build it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to get much of a performance gain from using a hash object in this scenario. The main benefit of using hash objects is that they allow you to merge on values from one or more small datasets onto a larger dataset without having to sort the large dataset. In this scenario:

- Both of your datasets are large
- You aren't doing any merging

Appending is possible via the use of hash iterators, if you're really keen, but I wouldn't bother. As other users have suggested, appending is the way to go here, as it will reduce the I/O requirements. Look at the documentation for `proc append` for more details.

Comment: For hash object, which one should be the "base" table, the small one or?

Comment: You want to avoid sorting the large table, which might be too big to fit into your available memory, so you load the small one into memory, as a hash object.